# Switch Statement: Homework Confusion

Tags: visual-c++

Question: What is *y* after the following switch statement is executed? Rewrite the code using an *if* statement.

```
y = 3; x = 3;
switch (x + 3)
{
case 6: y = 1;
default: y += 1;
}
```

I'm at the beginning of the C++ hike. I don't know what do with this. It's not working in C++ Visual Studio 2013. I've put it in as is and nothing happens.

I use:

```
y = 3; x = 3;

switch (x + 3)

{

case 6: y = 1;

default: y += 1;

}

    return 0;
}
```

And nothing happens. I have both the answers but I have no clue how to get them...

```
y is 2
if (x + 3 == 6)
    y = 1;

      y += 1;
```

I'm strictly supposed to be using

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read up on the significance of `break` in a `switch` statement.

Comment: Here is a link which explains how to use switch statements correctly.
 http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/#switch

Comment: I'm strictly a visual learner. If I can't see it performed in front of me, I'm just not getting it. It's a wall that words alone won't break through. It has to be laid out for me. I have the answers... I just don't know how to form those answers with what I'm given. My book doesn't give many examples, so...

Comment: I am simply not understanding what I'm reading with the link given...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`switch` basics in C/C++:

- switch expression is evaluated once, at the beginning. Then the 1st matching `case` is executed
- after the `case` clause, the execution *falls through* to the next clause unless there's a `break`. Since this typically isn't what was indended, fall-throughs are normally documented with a comment or (if multiple cases refer to the same code) by stacking them together (`case 2: case 3: <code>`).

Comment: If you insist to see this with your very eyes, step through the code under the debugger and see the execution flow and variables' values step-by-step.

Comment: I have little than 2 hours to complete this work, which I've been doing for 8 hours, 3 stuck on this. I don't really understand any of this. I don't know how to construct what is need to get the answers above. I don't know what to do with x=3; y=3;. I put the entire code into Visual but get a blank screen.

Comment: Place the cursor on the `x=3` line and `F9` to set a breakpoint. Then, `F5` to run the program under debugger. You should see the breakpoint to be hit. Then `F10` to step-by-step.

Comment: [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for kernel32.dll]

Comment: Ignore this. You need the code window which should be highlighting the current statement and the "Locals" pane which should list the local variables.

Comment: Call stack, Error list, and Explorer are all I'm seeing.

Comment: `Debug->Windows->Locals`. It's probably already there, as one of the panes in the bottom panels.

Comment: int y = 3;    int x = 3;

Comment: I think that's right. If so, I still get the blank screen.

Comment: Of course you get blank screen. You don't `cout` anything (nor your question says that you should). Your request was to see how this code works, that's what you need debug stepping for.

Comment: Now, back to comment 4 you go.

Comment: Now I'm confused over the math and declaring x/y with int. Where is x = 3 used in case 6 or the default? Using y gave me the 2 but using x gave me a 3.

Comment: I should have been a little clearer. I'm only supposed to submit the answers. All answers are given to us, I just want to know the workings behind them for myself or there's no point in my taking this class.

Comment: y = 1; x = 3;  I get that (y += 1) is (y = 1 + 1--technically) but what of x? Where does it fit in?

Comment: `x` is assigned 3 and never changes (since it's never assigned again or subjected to the likes of `++`). The expression in `switch` evaluates `x+3` which is `6`, then jumps to `case 6` since it matches the result. Then, since there's no `break`, the execution falls through to the `default` clause.

Comment: Oh! That's all the x = 3; is for. I lost myself again with 'int y = 3;' initially--what purpose does it have again? Or how does it become 1?

Comment: It initially assigns `y` to `3`, obviously. Go and see this in debugger. `=` is an assignment operator (not a show of equality like it's in math).

Comment: 'switch' switches the variable from 3 to 1? Dyslexia is not my friend today.

Comment: Nope, it executes a `case` clause that matches the result of an expression. The "switch" here means to select which `case` to use - there can be any number of them.

Comment: What's the relevance of the 3 in 'int y = 3' then? Was it necessary to run the entire program? I ran it with 'int y' still came to 2.

Comment: Here, `3` in `y` plays no rule since `y=1` under `case:` reassigns it. But if `x+3` didn't match the `case:`, the execution would transfer to `default:` right away, using that value instead.

Comment: This is all a struggle to me... You don't know how helpful you've been to me!!! You've answered my questions.

Comment: ...and I'm saving this post. Thank you, sir!

Comment: The important thing to note is that in this particular case, the `default` clause gets executed in any case. So the corresponding code can be placed outside of `if` clause in the answer.

Comment: ...didn't know that. Just as important just the same. Do you tutor by the way? Just thought I'd ask.

Comment: You're welcome. For me, this was an exercise in getting through to my peer with the limited means.

Comment: Nope, but I am fairly good at communicating things: "He who thinks clearly, explains clearly". My father did do some tuition as a side job.